# manually set wifi card frequency on MacOS X

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wireshark

I'm using macOS High Sierra (10.13.6). I would like to sniff live wifi traffic on a specific wireless channel using Wireshark. I'm able to put the interface in monitor mode using Wireshark and see all the traffic passing on the network. But I can't find a way to change the wireless card channel in order to sniff on a different frequency. Like in the Sniffer Tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/usr/libexec/airportd
```

or

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport
```

Run them without arguments to see their usage statements, then use that info to figure out the right arguments to set the channel and width appropriately.